# how to solve the error in this program in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace comparision
{
    class numbers
    {
        private static string comparision;

       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number a:");

            string a = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number b:");

            string b = Console.ReadLine();

            if a > b;
                Console.WriteLine("a is greater than b");
            else;
                Console.WriteLine("a is greater than b");

            return;
            
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done wrong ?

Comment: When asking questions like this on Stack Overflow, always make sure to post *why* you think you have done something wrong. I suspect you're getting a compiler error, and if so, please post the error message and indicate which part of the program you're getting it on.

Comment: No parentheses around `a > b`

Comment: I don't think this would compile. The if statement should be if (a>b)  and you should remove the ";" following the "if"

Comment: No semicolon after the `else` either.

Comment: and if you want to compare numbers, you need to convert the input to numbers. Now you compare strings

Comment: There should be no ";" following the "else" as well.

Comment: `return` statement not required at the end of a method unless it returns something.

Answer (score 5):

If I assume I know what your end goal is, here's everything that is wrong with your program:

- You can't compare strings with just `a > b`. At the very best this would be a *lexicographical* comparison, which would compare the string `"2"` to be "greater than" `"10"`, because it compares it character by character.
  I guess you actually meant the two things you input to be *actual* numbers, in which case you either want:

  ```
  int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // if integers (whole numbers)
  ```

  or

  ```
  double a = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // if floating point
  ```

  And same goes for the `b` variable

  However, `<` and `>` are not defined for string comparison. If you *actually* want to do string comparison, and not numeric comparison, you could use one of the members of the `StringComparer` class to pick the type of string comparison, such as `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Compare(a, b)` which would return a number less than 0 (if `a < b`), greater than zero (if `a > b`) or equal to zero (if `a == b`).
- The syntax for an if-statement is `if (...)`, not `if ...;`
- The syntax for `else` doesn't require a semicolon. What you've actually done is to say "else do nothing", the semicolon means "do nothing" when placed like this. You want to take that out.

As for other improvements, that aren't actual *errors*:

- You don't need a `return` statement for a method that returns `void`, if it's the last thing you do in the method
- You have no use for the static string field you've declared
- The two messages you output are the same, which means the program will say the same regardless of which number is the greatest one
- What happens if you input two equal numbers?

So here's one different version of your program:

```
namespace comparision
{
    class numbers
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number a:");

            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter number b:");

            int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (a > b)
                Console.WriteLine("a is greater than b");
            else if (a < b)
                Console.WriteLine("a is less than b");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("a is equal to b");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is useful but still I am getting the error 
comparision.cs(9,21): error CS0017: Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains the entry point. [C:\Users\bhumi\OneDrive\Desktop\CSharp\username\username.csproj]
comparision.cs(7,31): warning CS0169: The field 'numbers.comparision' is never used [C:\Users\bhumi\OneDrive\Desktop\CSharp\username\username.csproj]
Program.cs(7,31): warning CS0169: The field 'Program.userName' is never used 

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok at the beggining I think you make some mistakes. From the start conditional for *if* should be inside () and after it you don't use semicolon same with *else*. You can't compare strings like that so you need change type for *a* and *b* for example on int and Convert string input in int. Here is corrected code:

```
    namespace comparision
    {
        class numbers
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number a:");

            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number b:");
    
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    
            if (a > b)
                Console.WriteLine("a is greater than b");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("a is not greater than b");
    
            Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```